# how do i show an image in laravel with infyom crud generator

Tags: php, laravel, crud, infyom

i have been trying to show an image that i already stored on a folder and stored the path in the database, i need to show it on the edit page that i created using the infyom CRUD generator.

Been trying like this and even adding the img tag but it just displays the broken image

```
<!-- Product Image Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
{!! Form::label('product_image', 'Imagen:') !!}
{!! Html::image('product_image') !!}
{{ HTML::image(Storage::url('product_image')) }} 
{!! Form::file('product_image') !!}
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

any tips / hints or help on this is greately appreciated. thanks

Comment: just get the storageUrl of the image and try to access it on new ta to make sure that the storage url is valid

Comment: @Saengdaetcan you provide an example? thanks

Comment: just do `inspect element`, then see the url

Answer (score 1):

Hello @SolarConfinement Vishal Here from InfyOm and we are not supporting image Right now using CRUD generator thanks.

But you can get you image path and show it into blade.